# Trying to get Card id for the selected card which is in @foreach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel

Good Morning,
I am new to Laravel and work on home project. Here i am trying to show the month name (12 month with year) in card which can be selected and then show the detail table showing the data for that selected month.
I get the month name in array and shown the same in card using for each loop. Now i want to select the card for any month and base on the id of that card (which is month+year) i need to get the data from database and show it in another table.
Here i am not able to get the card id for selected card (error - undefined).
below is the code

```
 <!--/ Card -->

    <div class="row">

      @foreach ($getmonths as $item )

        <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 mb-4">
          <div class="card maincard h-100 align-items-center getmonthsale">
            <a href="#" id="{{ $item }}" value ="{{ $getmonths[0] }}" name="{{ $item }}">
              <div class="row row-bordered g-0">

                <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pb-0 pt-3 mb-0">

                  <div class="card-title text-center d-flex align-items-center mb-0">
                    <h6>{{$item}}</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      @endforeach

    </div>

  <!--/ Card -->
```

code where i need to get the monthname and use to ajax for further action

```
 $(".getmonthsale").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          var requested_to = $(this).attr("id")
          alert(requested_to);


          //$.ajax....
        })
```

image for ref.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is because `<div class="card maincard h-100 align-items-center getmonthsale">` does not have `id` attribute. you could add `data-id="{{id_from_db}}"` then in `var requested_to = $(this).attr("id")` change to `var requested_to = $(this).getAttribute('data-id');`

Comment: you might need to change the code to suit your needs.

Comment: @mr.kenneth `{{id_from_db}}` will not work and needs to be `{{$id_from_db}}`

Comment: Please next time if you have a JS question that is not depending on the backend code, then post a [mcve] using rendered HTML, JS and relevant frameworks, preferably in a stacksnippet (accessed via the `[<>]` button in the editor)

Comment: then use {{$id_from_db}} I did not include the `$` since I dont know what your variable is.

Comment: sorry I was just saying it wasn't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected :

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($getmonths as $item)
        <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 mb-4">
            <div class="card maincard h-100 align-items-center getmonthsale" data-month="{{ $item }}">
                <div class="row row-bordered g-0">
                    <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pb-0 pt-3 mb-0">
                        <div class="card-title text-center d-flex align-items-center mb-0">
                            <h6>{{ $item }}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".getmonthsale").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var requested_to = $(this).data("month");
    alert(requested_to);
    // $.ajax...
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to up vote but this app is broken for some reason add comment and will upvote

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because the id is on the first child of the element you are selecting using jQuery `$(this)`. you do what Kenneth said or get the first child and it's id.

```
var requested_to = $(this).children().first().attr("id")
```